# Babel-node + mocha + babel-istanbul, Unexpected reserved word 'import'

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, babeljs, istanbul

I am trying to run my unit tests and am running into an issue when adding some new code with the `import` key word being used. My set up, which was working before was just an npm script looking like:

```
 "test:unit": "babel-node node_modules/.bin/babel-istanbul cover --config=istanbul.json --dir coverage/unit node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- 'client/components/**/*.spec.unit.js' --require node_modules/ignore-styles --require node_modules/mock-local-storage"
```

This was working great for a few months until I added an import key word into my code. Now it is throwing the error `'Unexpected reserved word',` and pointing to the import.
My `.babelrc` is working fine when compiling on a webpack server. I assumed that this would be looking at the .babelrc. Just in case - here is the `.babelrc` :

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
}
```

Can't seem to find a working solution. Anyone know how to solve this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a compiler to transpile your test suites.

That's `--compilers js:babel-core/register`

```
 "test:unit": "babel-node node_modules/.bin/babel-istanbul cover --config=istanbul.json --dir coverage/unit node_modules/.bin/_mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register 'client/components/**/*.spec.unit.js' --require node_modules/ignore-styles --require node_modules/mock-local-storage"
```

Take a clue [here](https://github.com/mentrie/todoList/blob/master/package.json#L7).

**N.B:** Instead of `node_modules/.bin/_mocha`, you just need `_mocha`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks like it's working, but it's now no longer using the ignore styles ( the `--require node_modules/ignore-styles`)

Comment: Take another clue [here](https://github.com/mentrie/media-library/blob/master/package.json#L45-L46)

Comment: Is there a certain syntax for multiple compilers? js + css, I tried googling and comma separating and can't find anything that works. thanks for your help!

Comment: For js, you can skip files that you don't want to test. You can use `-x` flag to skip files. See [here](https://github.com/mentrie/Document-Management-System/blob/master/package.json#L10)

Comment: Sorry took me so long to reply - your original fix is giving me `Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern: js:babel-core/register`